# Using Youtube API for stop video by playing another one

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to stop emebed youtube video when another one is played on the same page, I found this:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942916/pause-youtube-iframe-embed-when-playing-another)
[fiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/B6ZyJ/3/)
But when i try to use it on my web page it doesn't work:
[my_test](http://www.giorgiopassino-mountainguide.com/beta/prova_vdo.html)

SCRIPT

```
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    var $ = jQuery;
    var players = [];
    $('iframe').filter(function(){return this.src.indexOf('http://www.youtube.com/') == 0}).each( function (k, v) {
        if (!this.id) { this.id='embeddedvideoiframe' + k }
        players.push(new YT.Player(this.id, {
            events: {
                'onStateChange': function(event) {
                    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                        $.each(players, function(k, v) {
                            if (this.getIframe().id != event.target.getIframe().id) {
                                this.pauseVideo();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }))
    });
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
One: 
<iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video     player" width="160" height="100" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed    /zXV8GMSc5Vg?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net">    </iframe>
<br/>
Two:
<iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="160" height="100" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LTy0TzA_4DQ?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net">    </iframe>
```

What's wrong? I've created the project on google developers, i've created the API key but i don't know where i must put that.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the jquery lib ( https://code.jquery.com/ )

Comment: It was a mistake but now I've inserted the jquery lib but it still don't work

Comment: I've inserted the last lib <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I've tried also by insert this but still not working: `var GoogleAuth; // Google Auth object.
function initClient() {
  gapi.client.init({
      'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
      'clientId': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
      'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest']
  }).then(function () {
      GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
  });
}`

Comment: Change this.src.indexOf('http://www.youtube.com/') to this.src.indexOf('https://www.youtube.com/') and set the link to players also to https  src="https://www.youtube.com/ and change this.pauseVideo(); to this.stopVideo();

Comment: Also set the whole script just before the </body> instead of the header

Comment: I've tried to do what you told me @ceasar but it still don't work [http://www.giorgiopassino-mountainguide.com/beta/prova_vdo.html](http://www.giorgiopassino-mountainguide.com/beta/prova_vdo.html)

Comment: Nobody can help me? 

I've tried by using the other solution where the iframe is created using code and not by embed it:(http://www.giorgiopassino-mountainguide.com/beta/prova_vdo2.html) and with this solution it works but in my case the user must embed the iframe itself from Youtube.com

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
The problem was that in the example they used the "origin" parameter, this parameter if setted avoids the introduction into the page of malicious third-party JavaScript code, which can take control of the YouTube player.

src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LTy0TzA_4DQ?enablejsapi=1&**origin=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net**"

This is why the code work on the fiddle page but not on mine.
So i've changed this origin path with my complete URL of the host page and now it work!